# Facing Failed to read stream error - mysql_native_password error

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.6

I have been facing the following error intermittently on MySQL.

> Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method
>   'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream
>   has failed.

It comes up any time and I am at my wits end. I also posted a bug on MySQL bugs and solutions are not proving to be effective in any way.I hope you guys can help me out.

Here is the link to MySQL Bug for details: [Reading from stream failed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76597)!

Some more detail: I have a client-server system but this bug occurs on the server system, where MySQL database is installed, when a local running app on the server system tries to run a query.

I had already opened a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460779/mysql-reading-from-stream-failed) but since has been dead. Just a caveat I thought that skip-name-resolve solved the issue but it seems to just have lowered the frequency. Hope someone would help me out this time around.

Comment: Percona.com and MariaDB.com have support teams that would love to be paid to solve it.